# Super User or SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, support

Officially, how are we supposed to write Super User?

- SuperUser (NO space)
- Super User (WITH space)

I'm constantly wondering about this whenever I go to write Super User, etc, and I've seen all styles of writing it...what do you think?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Super User with the space. As seen in [the About](https://superuser.com/about) and FAQ.

> Super User is a Q&A site for computer enthusiasts that's free.

No space usually comes up when people CamelCase the URL and it just sticks for them.

Comment: There also isn't much of a space between the r and the u in the logo, which is the most clearly visible depiction of the name of the site. (Though it's clearly visible in the tab title and the hint text in the search box.)