# What is the correct way to style this community's name?

Tags: discussion

If I'm writing about the website at https://superuser.com/, and I wish to refer to it by name, should I call it:

- Super User
- SuperUser
- Superuser
- superuser

Or something else?

(Context: I'm modifying [a tag wiki on another SE site](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/technology) to include a pointer to SU, and I figured I might as well check to see how you folks prefer the name to be styled.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Super User or SuperUser?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1213/super-user-or-superuser)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The correct name is **Super User**. For more information, see the [Stack Exchange Trademark Guidance page](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

> Stack Overflow is a programmer Q&A site on the Stack Exchange Network. As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters). The website domain name is always written **stackoverflow.com** (no CamelCase, single word capitalization rules apply). Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User (superuser.com), etc.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks!

Comment: Well, TeX.SE does whatever it wants, style-wise, but that's understandable ;)

Comment: I've been guilty of using CamelCase (SuperUser). I repent of my sins.

Comment: Why then does Stack Exchange use camel case in every graphic representation: "StackExchange"?

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek the logos are separate from how it is spelled out. I don't work for Stack Exchange, so I can't authoritatively answer any more specifically, but you're welcome to ask a separate question on the issue here or on [metaso].